# What was the significance of the spore that landed on Tilly's shoulder in Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, spore-drive

In the Star Trek Discovery episode [S01:E13](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What%27s_Past_Is_Prologue_(episode)) *What's Past is Prologue* we see a spore landing on Tilly's shoulder.

[image]

There is some speculation about this:

- An opening for Hugh to return?
- Mirror Lorca possession?
- A tardigrade egg?
- some personality remnants of the real Captain Killy.

My question is: **What was the significance of the spore that landed on Tilly's shoulder in Discovery?**

Comment: A deleted comment was saying to watch a certain episode in S2, but I can't remember which one.

Comment: The answer was given in https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Point_of_Light_(episode)

Comment: @EdmundDantes - I stand corrected. You should post that as an answer to the question, not a comment

Comment: @Valorum, I know, but I was too lazy to do that that evening, so I left it for somebody else to claim :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Major season 2 (episode 3) spoilers, so if you don't want them, don't continue reading.

> The spore was from the jump back to the prime universe from the terran universe.  The spore was a mirror-spore which got into Tilly and infected her.  After coming into close contact with the dark-matter asteroid fragment, it began communicating with Tilly.   It appeared as an apparition of her dead school friend.
> The infection was removed and placed into containment by Stamets.

Comment: Can you confirm in which episode this is revealed and provide an actual quote?

Comment: S2E3 at the very end of the episode

Comment: It's a bit hard to quote since it was a major plot point of S2E3.

Comment: It wasn't a "mirror-spore". It was simply a spore. Remember: the mycelial network is between the prime and mirror universes.

Comment: @Pod It was specifically discussed in the episode that it was a spore from the mirror universe, since all members of the engineering team were inoculated against the spores in the prime universe.

Comment: I guess I'll have to re-watch as I missed that info :) Thanks

Comment: @Pod which is exactly what I did (because my wife got hooked on it).

Comment: @Stephen Not the mirror universe, they say it's not from their dimension and in the next episode, it is made clear that it is from an in-between dimension where spores recycle interdimensional garbage. There are countless dimensions connected by the mycel network, not two.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking the spore was from the mirror universe.  The network inhabits some kind of inter-dimensional space, but the spores exist in a concrete universe.  The spore that landed on Tilly's shoulder was one from the mirror universe as specifically mentioned by Stamets.